# How to get two parts Adb(Android debug bridge) commands results in C#

Tags: android, shell, command, adb

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[e.t picture below, there are two parts adb command, when I input 'exit' part command, I want to get the result below,The difficulty lies in that i input 'autobt ...' part ,it did not realy return to the shell state, I need to input 'exit' command to compute and exit to shell state, so i can't use StandardOutPut.ReadToEnd method to get the results ,it will be
stuck forever

```
C:/Users/......>adb shell
ailabsz06:/ #                         -----enter the shell command
ailabsz06:/ # autobt nsrx -c 39 -n 0  -----part one command
BT device power on success
Rx pattern: 0x04
R channel: 20
Packet type: OxOf
Tester address: 88cOffee
Non-Signal-Rx test start.
exit                                  -----part two command
Non -Signal-Rx test complete
Total received packet: 2257
Packet Error Rate: 0.000000%
Total received payload byte: 60939
Bit Error Rate: 0: 000000%
BT device power off
ailabsz06:/ #                ----after exit command,enter shell again
```

I want to get this out for two weeks, I search the answer for long time, but i still get it out. so i really want your helps.

Had anyone encountered this problem, give me a chocolate, tks.

Comment: Why don't simply execute `adb shell autobt nsrx -c 39 -n 0` the you don't have to execute exit at the end. Alternatively you can read the data from StandardOutput using `ReadLine` and process it. If the process ends the OutputStream will also end.

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot.  simply execute ```adb shell autobt nsrx -c 39 -n 0``` simply start  receiving,I have to execute ```exit``` command to end the autobt command and count the received packects.

Comment: Ok, so the `exit` command is interpreted by `autobt` not by the shell. Still what I wrote `readLine` should be the way to solve this problem. Best way would be to perform the `readLine` loop in a separate thread.

Comment: Hi @Robert , yes i had tried ```ReadLine``` to get the ```OutputStream```, but i did not use a separate thread to do so. Thanks for your kindly.